# Twice press button for functionality on android

Tags: android, android-button

I want to implement the button on android. That button has two functions, single press to toast message, if the user instantly press button twice within millisecond then it will show the alert dialog, if delay to press than it will show toast message.
Please give me some idea how to perform these functions android Button.

Comment: why can't you implement click and long click listner for that button...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

Create a boolean before onCreate

```
private boolean pressedOnce = false;
```

In onClickListener use an handler for a second

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {


                if (pressedOnce) {
                   // show the alert dialog
                }

                pressedOnce = true;
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Clicked once!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        pressedOnce=false;
                    }
                }, 1000);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 3):

In your activity before onCreate declare

```
private long lastclicked = 0;
```

then setOnClickListener

```
 button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
     //1000 replace your time in ms
    if (SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - lastclicked < 1000){
        return;
    }
    lastclicked = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();


    //perform here your task

   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use customButton and **implements GestureDetector** , Then you can override **onSingleTapConfirmed and onDoubleTap** funciton

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to the solutions presented above is to use Android-provided `GestureDetector`, which allows you to detect, among other gestures, a double tap.

First you need a simple nested class to handle your double tap:

```
private class DoubleTapListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {
    @Override
    public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {
        // Handle your double tap here.

        return true;
    }
}
```

`GestureDetector`'s default listener interfaces allow you to listen on many various touch events. `SimpleOnGestureListener` provides an empty implementation of each of their methods, so you can implement only the ones you are interested in.

Next you need to create your `GestureDetector`. You can do this in `onCreate` of your `Activity`.

```
DoubleTapListener doubleTapListener = new DoubleTapListener();
GestureDetector gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(this, doubleTapListener);
gestureDetector.setOnDoubleTapListener(doubleTapListener);
```

Unfortunately you need to pass your `doubleTapListener` twice - the first time it is passed as `OnGestureListener` to provide all the empty implementations for the methods that does not interest us. `this` represents `Context`.

The last part is to route your onTouchEvent to our `GestureDetector`.

```
button.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(motionEvent);
    }
});
```

This solution requires slightly more code, but on the other hand you rely on standard Android's way to detect double taps instead of creating your own.